# Restore Database clarifications

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a 1 TB database. I started restoring the database(full backup) with No recovery and replace .In between there is a windows msi installer which installed .net framework 4.6.1 needed a reboot of machine and server got rebooted. After reboot now the database is in restoring mode. But I feel restore is definitely not successful. So now my plan is :

```
Restore Database DBNAME with Recovery
```

does not work in this case.

1. Take the database offline.
2. Delete the database and re start the restore of full backup again with no recovery and replace.

Please advice if this approach is correct.Or what I am thinking is wrong.

Comment: did you try using the `restart` clause?

Comment: @Sean Gallery,I am in a thinking that restore operation was not interrupted but it was completely broken operation.@Sean will REPLACE option work in my situation ?

Comment: The whole point of the `restart` keyword in the restore command is for purposes like this. Replace it not what you're looking for.

Comment: @SeanGallardy,yes sorry it was a typo mistake.Can you please let me know if RESTART clause will take over the operation where it stopped or will it start the operation from beginning again ?

Comment: It should start over, relatively close (if possible) from where it was interrupted.

Comment: Let us know how it works out or if you receive any errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since database server was rebooted while restore process was still going on so the restore process did not completed successfully.Restoring database with recovery is not going to work it will flash an error. What you have to do is

1. Open new query window, connect to master database and drop the database which is in restoring state by `drop database db_name;`
2. Now start the restore process again.

You should have waited to restart the machine after it prompted for reboot. I am sure it would have prompted but you would have selected for reboot then only it went ahead and rebooted. Avoid rebooting SQL servers when restore process is going on this would disrupt restore process and you would have to start all over again, which is waste of time.